# Adding a field to a table that is the result of a query to another table

Tags: subquery, ms-access-2010, default-value

In MS Access 2010, I have two tables - one with Candidates and one with Package Actions. The Actions are associated with the Candidates via the CandidateID field, which is an autonumber in the Candidates table. The Actions table has a date field for each action. I have a field in the Candidates field that I would like to display the action type of the most recent action associated with that particular candidate, but can't seem to figure out how to do it. I've tried implementing a subquery as a default value:

```
SELECT TOP 1 ActionT.ActionType FROM ActionT WHERE
(((ActionT.CandidateID)=13)) 
ORDER BY ActionT.DateCompleted DESC;
```

Obviously, this query on its own only returns the most recent action for candidate 13 but ideally I would like to replace the `=13` with `=CandidateID` but I can't even get the field to populate with the result of the query as is. I've also tried using `DLookup` but got an error while trying to make that the default value. I've also tried using the button "Modify Lookups", pasting the query and the DLookup directly into the cell, and trying to change the type of the field from "Text" to "Calculated", all to no avail.

Novice MS Access user here, so I appreciate any extra explanations y'all may have.

Thanks In Advance.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I'm not looking for a query, per se. I want to know how I can make the result of my query above always be the value of a field in the candidate table. (If my code above needs corrections, I'm open to that, but that isn't really my question.)

Example: Candidate A has several actions in theActionTable associated with him. They are ResumeRecieved, ResumeReviewed, and Interviewed. The date associated with Interviewed is the most recent, therefore in the CandidateTable, the status for Candidate A should be "Interviewed." We then decide to extend an offer, so we add an action to the ActionTable "OfferExtended."

The Status field in the CandidateTable for Candidate A should automaticaaly update to read "OfferExtended"

Answer (score 0):

Inside your main SELECT STATEMENT, you need to have a nested SELECT STATEMENT descendingly ordered by DateCompleted to get the most recent DateCompleted for each CondidateId.

Below should do the trick for you:

```
SELECT con.Id, 
       con.Name, 
       (SELECT TOP 1 ActionType FROM ActionT 
        WHERE CandidateId = con.Id ORDER BY DateCompleted DESC) AS ActionType
FROM Candidates AS con
```

Comment: How do I make this a field in my table? I tried addung a calculated field in the Candidate Table and using this as the "expression" but that didn't work. I got an error that said 

`This error can be caused by one of the following:

The maximum number of columns allowed in a table or the maximum number of locks for a single file is exceeded.

The indexed property of a field is changed from Yes (Duplicates OK) to Yes (No Duplicates) when duplicate data exists in the table.

An expression is not specified in the Expression property of a calculated field.`

Comment: Also, this would appear to return, ID, Name, and Status. All I want is Status, but I want the most recent status in the ActionTable that is associated to a particular candidate to be the value in the field on the Candidate table for that candidate.

Comment: This is an unfortunate that you cannot select a field from another table using calculated datatype although there are other ways to manipulated a field such as creating an update query and running it to inject a value (recently "ActionType" in your case) into a specific table.